# select all the rows in the rows in the tableview programatically in ios using swift on a button click?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to change the label text of all the cells in a tableview in ios by clicking on a button which is not a part of the tableview. I have tried searching documentation over the internet but haven't found a solution thus far.

Comment: please show us your code and also briefly describe your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the button action you should modify your datasource and then call `tableView.reloadData()` which will reload the table using the updated datasource.

Answer (score 1):

var isSelected = false

```
@IBAction func yourButtonAction(sender:UIButton)
{
    isSelected = True
    tableview.reloadData()
       
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(“YourCellIdentifier”, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCell

    if isSelected
    {
            // Set your text here
    }
    else
    {
        // Set default value
    }
}


if you want to change text to previous state when user tap again on button then use.

@IBAction func yourButtonAction(sender:UIButton)
{
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
    isSelected = sender.selected
    tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create datasource for all items contained in tableview, and then after modifying it just reload all of the data ...

for example you've got 3 items:

```
let item1 = "A"
let item2 = "B"
let item3 = "C"

let tableViewItems = [item1, item2, item3]

func tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath..., indexPath ... ) {
   // bind your custom datasource to tableview
   let cell = ...
   let item = tableViewItems[indexPath.row]
   cell.title = item
}
```

Then you've got your button action:

```
func didPressModifyAllButton() {
   for item in tableViewItems {
      // here you can modify your items
      item = "Modified ..."
   }

   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I am using this. let totalRows = markAttendanceTable.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) for row in 0..<totalRows { var cel = markAttendanceTable.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 2, section: 0) as IndexPath) as! MarkAttendanceTableViewCell cel.checkBox.isChecked=true

Comment: Problem is that since it is reusing cells, it is giving me an exception

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

You have to maintain array for selectedIndexPath, Once you click a button, you can add all the Indexpath to the array.

Option 2: 
You have a boolean variable which can be maintained to show selection in tableView.

Answer (score 0):

// Hi, try like this

```
func buttonClik(sender: UIButton) {
     sender.selected = !sender.selected
      tblView.reloadData()
}

set text of label based on button selection as follows 
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if btn.selected {
      //give text of label on selection state of button
    } else {
       //give text of label on normal state of button
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this. let totalRows = markAttendanceTable.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
            for row in 0..<totalRows {
                
            var cel =  markAttendanceTable.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 2, section: 0) as IndexPath) as! MarkAttendanceTableViewCell
            cel.checkBox.isChecked=true

Comment: Problem is that since it is reusing cells, it is giving me an exception

Comment: u can get that cell in cell for row at indexpath, u can change text of label based upon the button slection

Comment: why u are takingall cells in diffrent method